# Virtualbox API CopyTo fail (C/C++)

Tags: android, c, linux, virtualbox

I want to copy a file(time.txt) form host(ubuntu12.04-64bit) to guest(android 4.0.3) via Virtualbox API. And the virtualbox is 4.2.4. As you see the C/C++ code below, the "all goes well." is printed, but I can not find "/data/local/tmp/time.txt".
Thanks for your help!

```
rc = guest->CreateSession(NS_LITERAL_STRING("testUsr").get(),
                          NS_LITERAL_STRING("testPWD").get(),
                          NS_LITERAL_STRING("android").get(),
                          NS_LITERAL_STRING("sessionName").get(),
                          &guestSession);
if (NS_FAILED(rc)) {
    printf("fail to CreateSession ! rc = 0x%x\n", rc);
    return -1;
}
rc = guestSession->CopyTo(NS_LITERAL_STRING("/home/hat/time.txt").get(),
                          NS_LITERAL_STRING("/data/local/tmp/time.txt").get(),
                          1, &flag, &sessionProgress);
if (NS_FAILED(rc)) {
    printf("fail to CopyTo ! rc = 0x%x\n", rc);
    return -1;
}
```

>

```
sessionProgress->WaitForCompletion(-1);
printf("all goes well.\n");
```